# Git clone: error: chmod on <ntfs mount> failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, permissions, git, mount

I'm dual booting fedora/windows 7, and so I have a common storage place between them I've made a small fat partition, mounted from `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=C37A-2B35 /transfer vfat users,umask=000 1 3
```

I'm trying to clone a git repository I have on linux to the mount, so I can get the project working on windows:

```
> git clone ~/myproject/ /transfer/myproject
Cloning into '/transfer/myproject'...
error: chmod on /transfer/myproject/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
error: chmod on /transfer/myproject/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
error: chmod on /transfer/myproject/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
error: chmod on /transfer/myproject/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
error: chmod on /transfer/myproject/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
error: chmod on /transfer/myproject/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have full write permissions, although root is the owner, which is why the `chmod` fails. Can I tell `git` to not `chmod` because it doesn't need to?

A workaround is this, which is really stupid and I shouldn't have to do it:

```
git clone ~/myproject/ /tmp/myproject && mv /tmp/myproject /transfer/
```

Comment: Same question on ubuntu.SE: [dual boot - Sharing git repo on NTFS partition between Linux/Windows dualboot - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423072/sharing-git-repo-on-ntfs-partition-between-linux-windows-dualboot)

Comment: My answer here might help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1268127 - Just mount ntfs-3g with no uid, gid, fmask, dmask, umask, permissions or acl option to disable permission checks (and chmod will just do nothing).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what worked for me. Change the `fstab` settings to mount the device as a specific user, as described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1880685&p=11455569#post11455569). The key options are `uid` and `gid`, which are presumably "user id" and "group id" respectively. I set them both to my username, and was able to clone successfully.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This also worked for me in WSL on Windows 10. I manually mounted the drive with -o metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000 (my user's uid/gid, seen by running the 'id' command). Thank you.

Comment: just adding the `uid` in `fstab` setting worked for me. Thanks. Wish I could have marked that as accepted answer.